# Why would CPCL code sent to a Zebra QLn220 printer work, whereas the same code does NOT work when sent to a Zebra QL220?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, zebra-printers, motorola, handheld

Based on user preferences (type of label selected, and whether to send a "Keep Alive" message), different CPCL commands are sent from a handheld device to a Zebra QL[n]220 belt printer. This code:

```
const string quote = "\"";
string keepPrinterOn = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}power.dtr_power_off{0} {0}off{0}", quote);
string shutPrinterOff = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}power.dtr_power_off{0} {0}on{0}", quote);
string advanceToBlackBar = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}media.sense_mode{0} {0}bar{0}", quote);
string advanceToGap = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}media.sense_mode{0} {0}gap{0}", quote);
```

...works for the (newer) QLn220 printer, but on the (older) QL220, rather than the printer receiving the commands and acting on them, it simply prints the raw commands onto the labels. IOW, the QL220 belt printer, instead of converting the commands to actions, or barcodes, it prints stuff like this directly on the label:

```
0 200 200 241 1
RIGHT
TEXT 4 3 0, 0 0.75
LEFT
TEXT 5 0 0 90 DRPEPPER (7X2) = 14
CENTER

BARCODE UPCA 1 1 50 0 137 054900000295
FORM
PRINT
```

Is it that something changed between the QL220 and the QLn220 as to the CPCL protocol, or...???

### UPDATE

Well, this is bizarre; oddly enough, I added this code:

```
string getDeviceLang = string.Format("! U1 getvar {0}device.languages{0}", quote); 
string setDeviceLangZPL = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}device.languages{0} {0}ZPL{0}", quote); 
. . . 
String deviceLanguage = PrintUtils.GetSettingFromPrinter(getDeviceLang); 
MessageBox.Show(deviceLanguage); 
if (deviceLanguage.Equals("line_print")) 
{ 
PrintUtils.SendCommandToPrinter(setDeviceLangZPL); 
}
```

...and although the call to GetSettingFromPrinter() returns an empty string (as seen in MessageBox.Show), the printing therefater works as desired anyway (it prints the labels as desired, instead of just printing the raw commands onto them)!?

### UPDATE 2

**Note:** My QLn220 Zebra printer *does* have a usb port (the older QL220, which is the one that was causing the problems, does not). When I sent it the "what language are you using" (getDeviceLang) command using Zebra Setup Utils, it responded with, "hybrid_xml_zpl"

Comment: Are you sure you aren't in line print mode on that printer?

Comment: No, I'm not; is there a command I can send to prevent that? I assume setting it OUT of line print mode if it is not in it would do no harm...??? Or is there a way to test if it is, and then change it only if so?

Comment: Looks like you can test it using `! U1 getvar "device.languages"` and set it via `! U1 setvar "device.languages" "line_print"`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. If it works, I'll have you make it an answer if you want.

Comment: Yeah sure.  I typically use Label Vista to configure a printer, so I cannot speak directly to using the `device.languages` field.

Comment: If Label Vista is something each printer owner/user would need to deal with, that wouldn't work for us. We need to do it for them in code without their needing to think about it.

Comment: Yep, I get that.  When wearing the developer hat, I am only dealing with a few printers.  Deployment and remote device management is handled by another group using software like Avalanche.  I'm spoiled :)

Comment: Come to think of it, isn't setting it to line_print what I DON'T want? That sounds as if it's just directly printing the commands sent to it...or am I misunderstanding the meaning of "line print"?

Comment: Yes, you don't want it in line print mode.  Start with using the first command to see if it is even in line print mode...

Comment: So if it is, I need:
! U1 setvar "device.languages" "ZPL"
apparently.

Comment: I see there are many other options too, though, such as "hybrid_xml_zpl", "EPL", and "epl_zpl" - argghhhh!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55390/discussion-between-tcarvin-and-b-clay-shannon).

Comment: Seems like it was in line print mode and you successfully took it out of line print mode.  Nice job!

Comment: I don't see how I did that - I just *checked* to see if it was...

Comment: Your code snippet includes the "set", no?....ah, just read it closer, you are saying you never ran the set code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hybrid zpl combines both CPCL and ZPL print commands.

Receipt printers (imz, em220...etc) are set originally from factory in Line print mode.  Some of the older QL220 are as well.  Its best to set them to Hybrid and you should have no problems.

Brent
Arrowhead Corp - Zebra ISV